# What's this mecha anime with a robot world championship?

Tags: daigunder

Ok, so this was a mecha anime. It was a series. The main story is that there was a boy who, along with his robots (I think they belong to him, also I think some of them were created by his grandpa ) are trying to win some kind of robot world championship. I just remember some scenes, which I am describing below

1. There is one scene where the boy's grandpa says that he left a sticker inside every robot he created, then one of the robots exclaims "huh! So that sticker is inside me also ?"
2. In one of the fights, one of the opponent's robots has a cobweb inside, due to which it cant function properly.
3. Then there is one scene where they go to train, and one of the robots was cutting wood, but the way he was cutting was curious, that he simply tapped the wood and it was cut perfectly (sides were smooth)
4. The main female character goes to another team, where she is assigned to work on only a limb of the robot. She quits saying that her team is the best( the main character's team ) and that she is returning to it

Please help me find this anime. Really important part of my childhood.

Comment: Might you have when you might have approximately seen it?

Comment: Could it be [Medabots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medabots)?

Comment: No. Its not medabots, I checked. As for the time, I saw it approximately 7-8 years ago. But I believe that it was released before dat

Comment: The main character has more than one robot

Answer (score 4):

OK I think I am pretty sure the anime you are looking for is [**Daigunder**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daigunder)

[image]

**POINT 1:** The main character is Akira Akebono and his grandfather, Hajime Akebono, is a famous research scientist who created the robots. He is like Ash Ketchum except with robots instead of pokemon. The robot which says ,"I have the sticker inside me too?"  is Daigunder units' human like AI robot called Ryugu, flaming robot warrior.

**POINT 2:** Coming to the cobweb thing, there is an episode where the robot malfunctions and tries to harm Ryugu even after the battle is over. Akira jumps in (like Ash saving Pikachu or hugging it to death ) and tries to protect Ryugu. I think they get disqualified for a that tourney. But Akira gains Ryugu's trust.

**POINT 3:** And the robot cutting wood must be Bulion, the blue thrasher. Its just a small scene in training. I don't clearly remember which episode.

**POINT 4:** The girl in question is Haruka, she at first thinks Akira is a dumb kid (as he really is). But eventually joins this team as a manager.She gets a job at her dream company I guess but instead, joins this team.

check this out for a list of episodes. But all you points come up within 4 to 5 episodes of the series. Hope this helps :D
https://www.google.com/search?q=daigunder+episode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=daigunder+episodes

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help !!!!!

Comment: glad i could help :D . Enjoy the dai dai dai daigunnddderr song :D